# how can i look for dynamic string with find elements by xpath?

Tags: python, selenium

I use this line of code in order to get links that contain '6z_04n'. However, this string changes according to the month. How can I put dynamically changing string value?

```
flag = '6z_' + month + 'n' // 6z_04n
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, '6z_04n')]")
```

I want something like:

```
flag = '6z_' + month + 'n' // 6z_04n
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, flag )]")
```

Unfortunately this is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) if you are on Python 3.6+:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(f"//a[contains(@href, '{flag}')]")
```

Alternatively, `str.format` does the same thing:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, '{flag}')]".format(flag=flag))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
xpath = "//"
xpath += "a[contains(@href, 6z_%sn)]" % month
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
```